# Read Titan JSON vetex in Titan 1.0 written using Titan 0.5 to JSON file

Tags: json, graph-databases, titan, gremlin

I want to export **Titan 0.5** graph edge to JSON file . I didn't find any api to `writeVertex`. How to export only vertex to JSON in titan 0.5?

Next that exported JSON i need to import in **Titan 1.0** and attach to graph. so how Titan 0.5 JSON is mapped to Titan 1.0 vertex structure? Whats right way to do both things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `writeVertex` option was only added with TinkerPop 3.x and thus only available to Titan on 1.x. In addition, if you are writing GraphSON from Titan 0.5/TinkerPop 2.x, you will find that it is incompatible with Titan 1.x/TinkerPop 3.x.

TinkerPop did provide some basic migration help for small graphs which you can read about [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_tinkerpop2_data_migration) and a migration guide for Titan 0.5 to 1.x was provided [here](https://github.com/dkuppitz/openflights), but there really aren't any options for dealing with the migration of single vertices. You would have to write your own migration code to do that.

Comment: What if i create subgraph in titan 0.5 and import it in titan 1.0 will that work?

Comment: You could export the subgraph, save it as GraphSON in 0.5, then use that link I provided to import it to Titan. I think that might work. To be honest though, I think it might just be better to do your own import code. It really shouldn't be that complicated and then you have complete control over how the import will work.